# How to create Tkinter GUI that accepts Malayalam Unicode as input?

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I write Malayalam Unicode script from keyboard in Text widget created using Tkinter in python. I tried by setting font to the Text widget as

```
self.area = tk.Text(self, height=5, width=45, font=('MLU-Panini', 15))
```

While entering input from keyboard shows '????' for characters.

Comment: What operating system? Tk can deal with any glyphs in the Basic Multilingual Plane of unicode and it seems Malayalam fits in there. Provided your font can display the neccessary characters and your input method can accept them from the keyboard everything should work. I can see such glyphs using Tk on windows at least (using `label = Label(text="\u0d21\u0d22")`

Comment: Thanking your comment...This is in Windows 7 platform..

Comment: Using label just display Malayalam characters. But cant enter Malayalam characters on Text widget in Tkinter from keyboard.